# Is Mei's weather robot Snowball an omnic?

Tags: overwatch

[image: Mei's robot Snowball]

[Mei's animated short](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tjcm_kI0n0) makes it apparent that Mei's robot friend Snowball is fairly self-aware, being at least as intelligent as Bastion or Orisa.

Previously I'd assumed that omnics and robots were interchangeable in the Overwatch universe, but I'm not sure whether the term would apply to Mei's weather robot.

Is Snowball considered to be an omnic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [wiki page on Omnics](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Omnic), it is specifically stated that Snowball is *not* an Omnic.

> In Overwatch, omnic and robot are just about interchangeable as colloquial terms. In this sense, for example, people are able to use both terms to describe a robot who possesses a complex artificial intelligence. **Drones like Snowball, on the other hand, do not implement qualified AI (which are manually controlled to follow specific and simple patterns); they cannot be called omnics.**

Furthermore, omnics are specifically created by the Omnica Corporation, which Snowball was not. From the [Omnic gamepedia page](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Omnic):

> Omnics are produced by omniums, automated robotics factories that were built with self-improving software algorithms which eventually became self-aware.

While technically possessing an AI of potentially complex properties, Snowball was not created by the Omnica Corporation (it was created by Mei herself, according to [Snowball's wikia page](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Snowball)), thus, is not an omnic.

Comment: Actually i believe this to be uncorrect. In the AnimatedShort Snowball seems to have an AI, as he decides to deactivates himself and charge the battery.

Comment: @Shaeldon Snowball most certainly has an AI and seams to be on par with bastion to say the least, BUT given the answer it seams Snowball is not created by the Omnia corp so he aint an omnic.

Comment: @ИвоНедев well Everything after the first quote was added after my comment

Comment: "Omnics are produced by omniums" Wouldn't that mean Orisa isn't an Omnic then?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Technically yes and no. Orisa was built from OR-15 parts by Efi, and to the best of my knowledge her AI/personality was also built by Efi. She's made from parts of an omnic, but unless there's clarification from Blizzard, there's nothing more than speculation on our part.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I think Orisa is considered an Omnic. At the very least, Zenyatta considers her to be one - occasionally, when he applies his orb of harmony to her, he'll something like "We walk as one, my sister." They're obviously not actual family members, so Zenyatta at least considers her to be the same "race" as he is.

Comment: @MageXy I believe Zenny refers to most of the other hero's as his brothers and sisters, so that may not be indicative of Orisa being an omnic

Comment: @Kaizerwolf According to Overwatch's lead writer Michael Chu: "[In Overwatch, omnic and robot are just about interchangeable as colloquial terms (it's the equivalent of Kleenex vs. tissue paper). In this sense, people would refer to Orisa as an omnic (as they would for Zenyatta and Bastion)](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753575904?page=2#post-31)"